# how to get variable returned from struts-2-jquery <sj:a> action oncompletetopics call

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a button "Show Me", which makes an AJAX call to get the name, if the call successfully returns the name, the button "Get Key" will show in target result div. How can I get the variable name in the oncompletTopics function? Righ now in script, the name is undefined.

The anchortag and terget div is:

```
            <div>
           <sj:a href="%{ajax}" dataType="text" targets="commands" onCompleteTopics="complete" button="true" >Get Name</sj:a>
        </div>


        <div id="comm" ><input id='commands' type='button' value='Get Key' style='visibility:hidden' /></div>

<script>
        $.subscribe('complete', function(event,data) {
                    if(name.lengh>0) {
                    $("#commands").attr('style', 'visibility:visible'); }
                });
</script>
```

the Action class is:

```
        public class AjaxAction{
    /* name */
    private String name;

    @Override
    @Action(value = "ajax",
    results =
    {
        results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "plainText")
    })
    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
            name = "my name";
            return SUCCES
    }

 /* get Name*/
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

/* set Name */
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The result should be `JSON`, not `Tiles`, imho.

Comment: Thank you, Andrea. If I remove the condition to check the name, as shown below, the Get Key button shows when I click the "Show Me" button. But how can I get the variable back from action? $.subscribe('complete', function(event,data) {
                    $("#commands").attr('style', 'visibility:visible'); 
                });

Comment: I changed the result to plainText, I still can't get the variable name from action to jquery script. Do I have to use JSON? thank a lot.

Comment: Here is the answer, have to use json. it works after I change the dataType to json in UI and change the struts result type to json.

Comment: glad that the comment helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, have to use json. it works after I change the dataType to json in UI and change the struts result type to json